# What's wrong with this html?

Tags: html, netbeans

My html that starts with:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.3" src="js/euDock.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.3" src="js/euDock.Image.js"></script>
  </head>
...
```

Netbeans says on the `<head>` line:

```
The tag content is unresolved, expecting one of <ISINDEX>, <BASE>, 
<TITLE>, <OBJECT>, <SCRIPT>, <META>, <LINK>, <STYLE>.
```

Why?

Comment: Can you show the full HEAD please?

Comment: What's the rest of it?  Those two lines are correct, but it sounds like there's something wrong on another line.  IDEs sometimes don't give you errors on the most sensible line.

Comment: You might be missing a `doctype`, but that's not what the error is complaining about

Comment: What is the extension of the document, and what is the associated type/editor for that file extension that you have set up in NetBeans?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I indeed asked for the full `head` to see whether there is a `title` element which is mandatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp

> The HTML title Element
>
> The  tag defines the title of the document.
>
> **The title element is required in all HTML/XHTML documents.**
>
> The title element:
>
> - defines a title in the browser toolbar
> - provides a title for the page when it is added to favorites
> - displays a title for the page in search-engine results

So for example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
    The content of the document......
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't title required within the head?